# Javascript Type Comparison

Tags: javascript, typeof

What is the best way to compare two variables for identical javascript types?:

I.E.

```
[] = ['1','2','3']
[] != {}
Number = Number
null = null
```

etc. etc.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To just compare types, one would think `typeof` would be the right tool

```
typeof [] === typeof ['1','2','3']; // true, both are arrays
```

Note that `null`, arrays etc. are of type `'object'`, which means

```
typeof [] === typeof null; // is true (both are objects)
typeof [] === typeof {};   // is true (both are objects)
```

which is expected behaviour.

If you have to specifically check for null, arrays or other things, you could just write a better `typeof` function

```
var toType = function(obj) {
  return ({}).toString.call(obj).match(/\s([a-zA-Z]+)/)[1].toLowerCase()
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/DUk96/)

Then you could do

```
toType([]) === toType(['1','2','3']); // true
toType([]) === toType({});     // false
toType(1) === toType(9999);    // true
toType(null) === toType(null); // true
toType(null) === toType([]);   // false
```

Comment: Love it! Exactly what I was looking for - Here's a random thought in my testing. What about function test(){} toType(new test()); which will appear as an object?

Comment: Yeah, but: function test1(){} && test2(){} will equal each other toType(new test1()) == toType(new test2()); - I don't really need this  tho, was just curious - actually don't worry about it lol, I'm fine with this. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, they are both of type `object`, so they will be the same with `toType()`. You can't really compare objects, as two objects are never the same, even `{} == {}` will be false, as two objects are never equal even if they contain the same things.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to distinguish object "types" from each other, it might be a good idea to compare their prototypes:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf([]) === Object.getPrototypeOf([1, 2, 3])
Object.getPrototypeOf({}) !== Object.getPrototypeOf([])
```

This will however throw if you're not passing in objects, so if you also want to compare the types of primitive values (including `null`) you will have to do more sophisticated tests:

```
function sameType(a, b) {
    var objectA = Object(a) === a,
        objectB = Object(b) === b;
    if (objectA && objectB)
        return Object.getPrototypeOf(a) === Object.getPrototypeOf(b);
    else if (!objectA && !objectB)
        return typeof a === typeof b;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

```
typeof 5 === typeof 37
typeof {} === typeof []
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for all "types":

```
function haveSameType(a,b) {
  return (a instanceof Array && b instanceof Array) ||
    (a === null && b === null) ||
    (typeof a === typeof b && 
     b !== null && 
     a !== null &&
     ! (a instanceof Array) &&
     ! (b instanceof Array)
    );
}
```